# Using Node's `response.end` method with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a basic HTTP server that responds to everything with "foo":

```
import http from 'http'

http.createServer((request, response) =>
  Promise.resolve('foo\n').then(s => response.end(s))
).listen(8888)
```

This works, but when I change the `.then` line to a shorter version:

```
Promise.resolve('foo\n').then(response.end)
```

It doesn't end the response. I must be missing something very dumb but can't think of what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `end` function has to be bound to the `response` object. You can explicitly do that, with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this

```
Promise.resolve('foo\n').then(response.end.bind(response))
```

---

When you pass `response.end` to `then` function, you are actually passing the function object to the `then` function. The actual binding between the function and the `response` object is broken. For example, inside the `end` function, if they refer the `response` object with `this`, it will not be there as we have broken it. That is why we have to explicitly bind the function object with the actual object.

For example,

```
function Test(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Test.prototype.printName = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
}

var test = new Test("thefourtheye");
test.printName();
```

will print `thefourtheye`. But if we do something like this

```
(function (func) {
    func();
}(test.printName));
```

it will print `undefined`. Because `test.printName` is actually the function object and it will not have any reference to `test`. So when it is invoked with `func()`, the `this` inside `printName` will refer the global object, which will not have `name` property defined in it. If we bind it like this

```
(function (func) {
    func();
}(test.printName.bind(test)));
```

`test.printName.bind` will return a new function which will actually invoke `test.printName` with the context set as `test`. That is why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is really unexpected though.

Comment: Learning Lua may help you to make sense of the syntactic sugar most object-oriented languages give you; there's always this first invisible parameter to every object-based function - "this" - that identifies which object the function is operating on. Even with object-based programming, functions are still somewhat static; they're not intrinsically tied to the objects they are assigned to. (That's a shortened explanation, but maybe something will "click" with you)